# Does sleeping in a bed provide a benefit?

Tags: timber-and-stone

Title says it all - does having your people sleep in a bed provide an advantage like faster fatigue regeneration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bed provides faster fatigue regeneration, so says the wiki. Also mentions something about healing, but doesn't say if it increases healing or not.

Comment: And the new cloth bed reduces fatigue faster than the old straw beds.

Comment: Here is a forum thread I found on this topic: http://www.timberandstonegame.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=3496